Role management in SQL Server
What is the best way to manage roles in sql server in Azure VMs (multiple). We want separate logins for each users but it should be same on all Azure SQL VMs. We are currently using windows Credentials setting credentials on credential manager for that server IP but it is too slow.

Are the Azure SQL VM member of an Active Directory Forest/Domain? That should help

Take a look at Microsoft Purview

@MBuschi, yes they are. But, we have two AD or Domains, one internal in local network and one on azure and we don't want to connect these two together.

So you're creating troubles to yourselves. Finally you have to set roles on one vm, export and then apply the same roles on the second one. Scripting is your ally.

@MBuschi I am fine if I can manage roles on Azure VMs only ignoring internal environment. Like I mentioned, we have multiple VMs on Azure under same AD. We do have roles managed on Azure as well but the issue here is when we manage roles with Windows authentication, we are managing credentials on Credential manager using ServerIP:port E.g. 1.1.1.1:1433 and connecting with SSMS with windows authentication, the connection establishing time is worse (like 7-10 sec) even when opening new query tab on that connection. However, if we do SQL authentication, its fast. So, we want a better solution.

Windows authentication by creating groups on AD.

Do you have a domain controllers next to the Azure VMs?
In the same AD site? Or they have to contact DC on prem for authentication?

@MBuschi Yes, the domain controller is installed on a VM which is on the same network as other sql server VMs. Also, they dont need to contact DC on prem for auth.

this is your porblem that has to be fixed but i don't understand your way to use windows authentication: "the issue here is when we manage roles with Windows authentication, we are managing credentials on Credential manager using ServerIP:port E.g. 1.1.1.1:1433 and connecting with SSMS with windows authentication, the connection establishing time is worse (like 7-10 sec) even when opening new query tab on that connection."

probably the mistake here is the usage of credential manager. why you are using it? isen't enought standard windows athentication?

@MBuschi, Our sql servers are located in Azure which are in a domain different from the PCs (PCs are in local onprem domain) used to connect to the sql server. And these two domains, onprem and azure are not interconnected. This is the reason we are not able to use the normal windows authentication to connect directly to the server and have to use credential manager for the purpose.

ah this is a relevant information! So use runas or trust the two forests or use a bridge Vm joined to that domain
